# Android Studio- Trouble with setting activity start delay

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, android-handler

This is my first question so sorry if I don't provide all the needed info. Just comment and I'll add it.

Onto the problem itself. I'm trying to make a splash screeen of sorts which consists of a short video. I want the app to start the following activity after the video ends, but after I start the app it just starts the second activity right away (Menu.class in the code). Once I'm in the Menu activity I can go back but all i see is a black VideoView. Also, the VideoView worked before I added the Handler. Not sure if it even could have been the problem (new to android studio) but doesn't work even after removing @Override (probably a stupidity, right?). Or can it be caused by the Menu.java activity? (It's just the standard pre-generated preset, I didn't make any changes to it)

```
public class splash_screen extends AppCompatActivity {
static long duration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    VideoView videoView = this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoView.start();

    duration = videoView.getDuration();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(splash_screen.this, Menu.class));
        }
    }, duration);
}
}
```

Thanks for any and every advice, and like I said let me know if you need more info on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoView need some time to warm up, so here:

```
videoView.start();
duration = videoView.getDuration();
```

duration could be 0, that is why handler fires immediately. To switch to the second activity you should remove handler part and use:

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
           startActivity(new Intent(splash_screen.this, Menu.class));
           finish();//close activity
     }
});
```

Comment: I'm facing some 8 sec delay in launching home screen,after playing welcome video,Do you know wy.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Use Thread.sleep(millisecond); If you are adding animation to your splash screen
The Full C O D E:

```
 Thread t=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }
       catch (InterruptedException e){
          }
            finally {

                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

It Gives a delay of 3 seconds,you can do animation part within it

Comment: The previous answer works okay for this scenario but thank you for your advice! Might be helpful int the future :)